# Lightning Web Component (LWC), Can I include both in identifier reference and hard-coded value in class attribute?

Tags: lightning-web-components, class, style

I can put an identifier in the class attribute of an element in a Lightning Web Component; double-quotes are omitted.

```
<th scope="col" class={flexipageRegionWidth}>
```

Or I can put a hard-coded class; double-quotes are included.

```
<th scope="col" class="myStyleClassName">
```

Is there anyone to include both?

If I try it as below, the identfiier is not interpreted and I get exactly "myStyleClassName {flexipageRegionWidth}" for the class attribute when the component renders.

```
<th scope="col" class="myStyleClassName {flexipageRegionWidth}">
```

Comment: Just make sure the property includes both values.

Answer (score 2):

Make a getter that combines the values.

```
get thClass(){
  return `${this.flexipageRegionWidth} myStyleClassName `;
}
```

Use like this:

```
<th scope="col" class={thClass}>
```